# UDP Port forwarding on Windows 10/11

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables, port

I'm trying to forward `TFTP` server port from 69 to higher ports to avoid permissions issues.

We're using the following command on the Linux (*Ubuntu*):

```bsh
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-port <higher_port>
```

So far we've tried to use the following tools on Windows 11 desktop

1. [How to Set Up Port Forwarding in Windows - maketecheasier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-set-up-port-forwarding-windows-10/)
2. [NetworkActiv AUTAPF 2.2.6 tool](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/networkactiv_autapf.html)

yet no success.

Can someone help us to setup this port forwarding rule on Windows 11 desktop PC?

Thanks in advance.