# autapf port forwarding tool - UDP port forwarding

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall, port-forwarding

We're using **NetworkActiv AUTAPF 2.2.6** tool on Windows 11 PC to setup a `TFTP` server on windows PC.

The configuration are as follows:
[image]

We're seeing timeout errors on our system with this setup as follows,

```
Timeout waiting for traffic
Resending packet OACK packet:
    options = {'blksize': '1468'} on sessions <tftpy.TftpStates.TftpStateExpectACK object at 0x00000184ECF2DB80>
Timeout waiting for traffic
Resending packet OACK packet:
    options = {'blksize': '1468'} on sessions <tftpy.TftpStates.TftpStateExpectACK object at 0x00000184ECF2DB80>
Timeout waiting for traffic
received traffic on main socket for existing session??
```

So our questions are,

1. How to properly configure the tool to forward the UDP packets from port `69`?
2. Where can we raise the support for this tool? (*http://www.networkactiv.com/ is non-functional*)

Related to, [UDP Port forwarding on Windows 10/11](https://superuser.com/q/1720098/1122241)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.